# What is a solution of $v(t)$ in the differential equation?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, laplace-transform

I has $Vs(t)$ as well as a wave form in picture. So what is a solution of $v(t)$ in the differential equation? I used Laplace transform for solving but it is incorrect. Next picture, it is a wave form of $v(t)$ when $Vm = 12V$, $T = 20ms$ but i must know the equation of v(t).

Thank you.
[image]

[image]

Comment: When you say solve by Laplace transform, how did you do that? What form did you use for the square wave? If you show your work on that step, it would be easier to help you find the error.

Comment: Thank you. I will sent my work on that step to your email.

Comment: @SomsakElect: Can you post that work here? Also, do you know the component values for $R, L, C$?

Comment: Please post the work you did here, in the above question. You should always show how you've approached the problem thus far so that others may help you find where you went wrong.

Comment: Also, are you interested in the solution only up to 200ms, or are you looking for a closed form that is valid for all time?

Comment: @rajb245: I interested all time.

Comment: @Amzoti: In graph, I used R = 1 Ohm, C = 1.0132mF, L = 10mH,Vm = 12V and T = 20ms. So frequency of circuit = 50Hz.

Comment: This is Laplace Transforms of v(t) http://image.ohozaa.com/i/66c/asqLKC.jpg

Answer (score 1):

The first step is to figure out the Laplace transform of the voltage source.

In order to not confuse the voltage across the capacitor and the voltage source ($V_s$), lets call $V_s = E_s$.

$E_s$ is a periodic voltage source with period $T = 20~ ms = \dfrac{1}{50}$ seconds (or a circuit frequency of $50$ Hz (Hertz)). Because $E_s$ is a periodic source with interval $\left(0, \dfrac{1}{50}\right)$ seconds, it can be defined analytically as:

> $$
>    E_s(t) = \left\{
>      \begin{array}{lr}
>        12 ~V ,~~~ 0 \lt t \lt \dfrac{1}{100}~ \mbox{seconds}\\
>        ~0 ~V,~~~ \dfrac{1}{100} \lt t \lt \dfrac{1}{50}~ \mbox{seconds} 
>             \end{array}
>    \right.$$

For a periodic function, $E_s$ with period $T \gt 0$, we have:

$$\mathscr{L}~(E_s(t)) = \dfrac{\int_0^T e^{-s t}E_s(t)~dt}{1-e^{-sT}} = \dfrac{\int_0^{1/50} e^{-s t}E_s(t)~dt}{1-e^{-s/50}}$$

However, we have:

$$\begin{align}\int_0^{1/50} e^{-s t}E_s(t)~dt & = \int_0^{1/100} e^{-s t}(12)~dt + \int_{1/100}^{1/50} e^{-s t}(0)~dt \\ \\ & = -\dfrac{12}{s}~(e^{-st})~\Bigr|_{t=0}^{t = 1/100} \\ \\ & = \dfrac{12}{s}(1 - e^{-s/100})\end{align}$$

So, we can simplify (note: $(1-e^{-s/50}) = (1-e^{-s/100})(1+e^{-s/100})$) and arrive at:

$$\mathscr{L}~(E_s(t)) = \dfrac{\int_0^{1/50} e^{-s t}E_s(t)~dt}{1-e^{-s/50}}=\dfrac{\dfrac{12}{s}(1 - e^{-s/100})}{1-e^{-s/50}} = \dfrac{12}{s(1+e^{-s/100})}$$

For the second part, we need the Laplace Transform of the second order differential equation:

$\mathscr{L}\left( \dfrac{d^2v}{dt^2} + \alpha \dfrac{dv}{dt} + \omega_0^2~v = \omega_0^2~ E_s\right)$, with $\alpha = \dfrac{R}{L}, \omega_0^2 = \dfrac{1}{LC}$, yielding:

$$(s^2~v(s) - s~v(0)-v'(0)) + \alpha (s~v(s)-v(0)) + \omega_0^2~v(s) = \dfrac{12~\omega_0^2}{s(1+e^{-s/100})}$$

Solving for $v(s)$ yields:

$$v(s) = \dfrac{1}{s^2 + \alpha~s + \omega_0^2}\left(\dfrac{12~\omega_0^2}{s(1+e^{-s/100})} + s~v(0) + v'(0) + \alpha~v(0)\right)$$

Substitute all of your initial conditions, resistor, inductor and capacitor component values and then do partial fractions on the right-hand-side and then find:

$$v(t) = \mathscr{L^{-1}}~(v(s)) ~~\mbox{Volts}$$

Note: the result above matches your posted result because $v'(0) = v(0) = 0, V_m = 12, T = \dfrac{1}{50}$.

[image]

Just replace the component values and find the inverse Laplace Transform and you are done.

Comment: I don't believe the closed form solution for all time is as simple as you make it out to be. Partial fractions / inverse Laplace transform that expression? I can't see how that comes to a closed form solution that does not involve an infinite series summation. You have to find all the zeros of $e^{-sT/2}+1$, of which there are an infinite number, then expand that as an infinite product of terms, and find the residues for each one individually. What you'd end up with is each component of the Fourier series of square wave filtered by the circuit response, summed up in an infinite series.

Comment: @amWhy: Yes, I don't know. Haha! Can you taught me about your alignment?

Comment: @Amzoti: This is my step about v(t) equation: https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B5CokoO3TjiicVdxMDJlZlMxdVE/edit but the result didn't match the wave form http://image.ohozaa.com/i/e28/LWyW2x.jpg when I replace the component values. So I think the new problem is the finding of the inveres Laplace Transform.

Comment: This is full version about my solution. I think it maybe has a problem: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5CokoO3Tjiiam9zRUZISERZeU0/edit?usp=sharing